# How can a black hole eject plasma?

Tags: black-holes, speed-of-light, plasma-physics

This [image](https://www.repstatic.it/content/nazionale/img/2020/04/07/161203722-ad043616-3433-4f0e-b2f1-698f7fc1731e.jpg) from an online Italian newspaper shows photographs of one of the most powerful phenomena in the cosmos.

[image: black hole]

Nothing, not even at the speed of light $c$, can escape a black hole one it has been caught. So how is it possible mathematically that a black hole, which "swallows" the stars and gas approaching its powerful accretion disk, can then eject some of the gas into two thin jets of plasma at speeds $V_{pl}$ close to the speed of light?

Comment: Proposed in 1977, not yet verified. But whatever the answer is, it is *not* $v_{pl}>c$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blandford–Znajek_process

Comment: @JEB Thank you for your comment. Mine was just a hypothesis to be tempted to say that $v_{\text{pl}}>c$. I have not understood your link.

Comment: I think the "dash" was some non-standard dash that wiki-P uses, that this little comment box refused to interpret. – vs -.

Comment: @JEB Ah...now I have understood..:-)

Comment: BTW: My relativistic magneto hydrodynamics class was taught by Blanford in '88, and I didn't understand it then, and haven't made progress in the meantime.

Comment: @JEB I have seen the formula and at first impression it seems to be the radius of Schwarzschild.

Comment: The jets come from close to the black hole, not from the black hole.

Comment: @RobJeffries I'm not very happy. Is there a mathematical explanation?

Comment: The Blandford-Znajek effect is one idea.

Comment: @RobJeffries But my question is not a duplicate of your link!

Comment: How does it differ from asking how jets originate from a black hole?

Comment: @RobJeffries I have asked a question hoping to have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black hole is defined by its event horizon. This is the point at which the escape velocity reaches $c$. But the accretion disc forms outside the event horizon, so stuff can still escape from it. It is this outer stuff that finds its way into the jets, super-accelerated beyond escape velocity by magnetic fields being dragged round the hole.

If the escape velocity at the point of acceleration outside the black hole is $V_s$ then $c > V_{pl} > V_s$.